# Moving an object to the same spot on another object after teleportation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Sorry about the title name but I don't know how to summarize it better, feel free to change it.

I'm trying to create 2d portals in unity, right now though using this script on the portals

```
OnTriggerEnter2d(collision other)
{
    if(other.gameobject.tag == "ball")
    {
        // portal2 is just a gameobject I input in the editor.
        other.transform.position == portal2.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my crude drawings but that causes this to happen:

What is does now

[image: What is does now]

But as you can see, no matter how the ball hits portal1 (The blue one) it will always come out in the center of portal2 (The orange one).

But I need it to do this:

What I need it to do

[image: What I need it to do]

where if the ball hits the top of the portal, it comes out the top, if it hits the bottom, it comes out the bottom, etc.

I don't know how do this though, both portals are the same size, and are just sprite swaps of eachother.

Comment: Hi, this code won't compile. You're lacking "void" as a type for the method, there is no lifecycle method called 2d, it's "2D" and "collision" is not a type. Even if you were to write "Collision" that is not a valid parameter to OnTriggerEnter2D, as that would be Collider2D. Please fix to include your exact code.

Comment: It seems to use a `Rigidbody2D` component so you shouldn't do anything through the `transform` at all but rather use `GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().position = ` to keep the Physics intact. It also seems to lose its velocity by moving it this way

Comment: @FredrikSchön I know, I'm was giving an example of what I could do, but I need the position of where to collider was touched, I don't know how to do that. What I wrote only knows if it was touched.

Comment: @derHugo Ok, I will keep that in mind and move the Rigidbody instead of the transform, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the (in your case: y) offset of the collision. I believe this would be the easiest solution, given that you're using triggers (thus getting Collider) and not collision (where you'd get Collision and thus have access to the `contactPoints`):

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "ball")
    {
        var offset = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        // Set x to 0 if you want to ignore the x offset value like your image suggests
        offset.x = 0; 
        other.transform.position = portal2.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but the ball seems to use a `Rigidbody2D` component so you shouldn't do anything through the `transform` at all but rather use [`RigidBody2D.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-position.html) to keep the Physics intact.

Comment: you also should use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of directly comparing strings using `==`. [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) is a little bit faster but more importantly: It throws an exception if the given tag is misspelled or doesn't exist at all. A "bug" that `==` would simply hide by returning `false` costing you some development time and nerves ;)

Comment: @derHugo I will keep that in mind as well, thank you

Comment: @Fredrik Schön **This solution is perfect and it solves my problem!** I do have another problem though that is not part of my original question, but can you also modify the movement force of the ball to match the rotation of the portal? So for example, right now it does [this](https://imgur.com/a/M9DPd5l) and [this](https://imgur.com/a/UBravVX) could we get it to do this [this](https://imgur.com/a/coswoYL) and [this](https://imgur.com/a/cbeWf0p)? Currently I get the ball moving by having the ball do this `rigidbody2d.velocity = transform.up * bulletSpeed;` to itself on start.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is when it collides get it's position in your code. Then use that position to decide where it should appear on the other. For example say the portals are 20 long and one portal is at 100 and one is at 200. When it collides you get that your ball is at 115. The next portals is at 200. You subtract the balls position from position of portal that the ball collided with and add what you get for example this one would be 15 because 115-100=15. So when you add them you would get 215. Then you would use 215 to change position bof the ball instead of just 200.

Comment: Long winded way of saying "find ball's positional offset from portal" =)

Comment: Ok, I can definitely look into doing it that way, how should the calculation of determining where to put the ball look like when it comes to the code?